# Mapping str_detect over a list of strings to detect a second list of strings

Tags: r, purrr, stringr

Take a list of strings:

```
strings <- c("ABC_XZY", "qwe_xyz", "XYZ")
```

I'd like to get all elements in `strings` that don't contain a specific substring

```
avoid <- c("ABC")
```

I can do this

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

strings %>% 
   .[!map_lgl(., str_detect, avoid)]
[1] "qwe_xyz" "XYZ"
```

What I'd like to do though is specify several substrings

```
avoid_2 <- c("ABC", "qwe")
```

And then map over the list as before (doesn't work)

```
strings %>% 
   .[!map_lgl(., str_detect, avoid_2)]
Error: Result 1 must be a single logical, not a logical vector of length 2
```

What I want is

```
[1] "XYZ"
```

The error is clear -  each element of `string` is generating a logical for each element of `avoid_2`, for total of 2 logical/element and `map_lgl` can only handle one/element.

I can of course do each substring separately, but I don't want to - I want to make a list of substrings

***don't want, but does work***

```
strings %>%
  .[!map_lgl(., str_detect, "ABC")] %>% 
  .[!map_lgl(., str_detect, "qwe")]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to the answers already provided, it's worth noting that `stringr::str_detect` and, therefore, `stringr::str_subset` are vectorised over both their `string` and the `pattern` arguments.  This means that you don't actually need any kind of explicit iteration (via loop, lapply, or map) or calls to `paste`:

```
library(stringr)

strings <- c("ABC_XZY", "qwe_xyz", "XYZ")
avoid_2 <- c("ABC", "qwe")

str_subset(strings, avoid_2, negate = TRUE)
#> Warning in stri_subset_regex(string, pattern, omit_na = TRUE, negate = negate, :
#> longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
#> [1] "XYZ"
```

Rather annoyingly, this generates a warning (which seems to stem from the underlying dependency on `stringi::str_subset_regex`). Crucially, though, it produces the expected results.

Answer (score 5):

One option could be:

```
strings[map_lgl(strings, ~ !any(str_detect(., avoid_2)))]

[1] "XYZ"
```

Or doing directly:

```
strings[!str_detect(strings, paste(avoid_2, collapse = "|"))]
```

Comment: `strings[!str_detect(strings, paste(avoid_2, collapse = "|"))]`
is the same as using
`strings[str_detect(strings, paste(avoid_2, collapse = "|"), negate=TRUE)]`

Answer (score 1):

We can loop over the 'avoid_2' pattern vector instead of 'string' as 'string' argument is vectorized (if the pattern is also of the same length as 'string', then both of them can be passed for elementwise checking), then `reduce` the logical vector with `|`, `negate` and `extract` the elements from the 'strings' vector

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
avoid_2 %>% 
    map(~ str_detect(strings, .x)) %>%
    reduce(`|`) %>% `!` %>% 
    magrittr::extract(strings, .)
#[1] "XYZ"
```

---

Or using `base R` with `grep` where we can pass the `invert` to get the opposite values of the matching pattern

```
grep(paste(avoid_2, collapse="|"), strings, invert = TRUE, value = TRUE)
#[1] "XYZ"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `paste` all the `avoid_2` strings together and `collapse` them with "|". This creates a regular expression that you can feed into `discard` and `str_detect`.

```
library(tidyverse)

strings <- c("ABC_XZY", "qwe_xyz", "XYZ")
avoid_2 <- c("ABC", "qwe")

avoid_2 <- avoid_2 %>% 
   paste(., collapse = "|")

avoid_2
[1] "ABC|qwe"

#discard any values in strings that are also in avoid_2
strings %>% 
    discard(str_detect(., avoid_2))
[1] "XYZ"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another method I found on RStudio community

```
library(tidyverse)

testlist <- list(
  list(aaa_x = 1, aaa_y = 2, aaa_z = 5, bbb_a = 333, bbb_b = 222),
  list(aaa_x = 7, aaa_y = 5, aaa_z = 6, bbb_a = 3939, bbb_b = 5635)
)

result_1 <- map(testlist, function(x) keep(x, .p = str_detect(names(x), "aaa")))

result_2 <- map(testlist, ~ keep(.x, .p = str_detect(names(.x), "aaa")))

identical(result_1, result_2)
```